# Is there a way to attach a VM instance from Azure as compute power to train your model locally?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, azure-ml

I have a python folder locally which does the training of the model.

I am wondering, is there a way, for example to bring some GPUs locally and just "attach them" to your script or do you need to do everthing on their portal in order to train your model?